# Sign in form always showing "Wrong Credentials"

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

```
<?php include 'header.php'; 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("layout",$con);
$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if($_POST["submit"] == "LOGIN" )
{
    $sql = "SELECT username,password from secure";
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_BOTH))
{
if($row['username'] == $name and $row['password'] == $password)
   {
     echo "welcome " .$name;
   }
     else
   {
    echo "Wrong Credentials";
   }
}
?>
```

This code is for a sign in form.

It's showing "Wrong Credentials" followed by "Welcome George", even if the username and password matches.

If the username and password doesn't match it shows as "Wrong Credentials" followed by another "Wrong Credentials".

Comment: Think your logic through with pen and paper, then it's obvious what the problem is.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT username,password from secure";` You'll need a `WHERE` clause to `SELECT` matching `username` and `password`

Comment: Debugging is a good key to see where you are wrong

Comment: You have a loop in your code. Better move your conditions into the SQL query as mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry, but how can you use such a stupid title? What does it say about what's your question about? Do you think anyone is posting a question here who doesn't want or need to get help? Do you think anyone wants or needs to help to make his code work incorrectly? Can you imagine everyone titles his question like that? It would make the Stack Overflow useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query/logic is completely wrong.

What you should do is check if that user and password combination exits in database using WHERE clause. But actually you are doing is fetching each row and checking for equality. In such situation you can also get n numbers of wrong credentials.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error()); 

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass'])) { 
      echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE..."; } 
else { 
      echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY..."; 
}
```

Here again a better check would be to check if number of rows==1, which is best practice and convention you should follow.

Comment: we should take " or die(mysql_error())" from the second line $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error()); inorder to make else part work. Thankyou